# asp.net core API best practice controller naming routing

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi

I need to create a ASPNET Core API in C# and I would like to know what would be the best convention in creating controllers and assigning routing to them.

I have a set of catalogs about 35, example:

- Employee Type
- Location
- Status Type
- Region
- Holiday Type
- Leave Type
- Language
- Country
- etc...

And on the other side I have to expose API for saving stuff just like updating patient info, etc.

So one way would be to create 35 different controllers just for the catalogs itself like, `EmployeeTypeContoller`, `LanguageController`, `CountryController`, `LeaveTypeController`, etc..

```
 [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class [CatalogName]Controller: Controller
```

But I don't think this is right, or on the other hand just create a `CatalogController` and have all the `GET` methods about each catalog inside.

If this is the case, then I will need to expose all of them in a path like:

- /api/catalog/language
- /api/catalog/country
- /api/catalog/employeetype
- etc..

What path should I follow?

Comment: You could specify the Route attribute and create only one controller.Refer to:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.1#attribute-routing

Comment: @Rena yes thats what I think is the right way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could specify the `Route` attribute and create only one controller.

Reference: [Attribute Routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.1#attribute-routing)

Answer (score 0):

I typically build my applications using good API practices. REST can really be considered as a set of principles that, when applied correctly in an application, benefit you with the architecture and standards of the Web itself. I would recommend creating a controller for each example resource CatalogController and within the class you do the routing for the Catalog. This is the best and recommended way for applications, through routing, an authentication must be created if you do not want to expose any API easily.

Ensuring data security is also part of the design of an API, today the main model used by the community is Oauth 2.0, this is an authentication standard, which was built to preserve a user's sensitive data, my recommendation would always be that it is possible to use it, however if it is not possible, do not leave your API without authentication, at least use a basic type authentication, where a base64 token is usually created from a user and password.

Comment: So you mean creating as many controllers as many catalogs I have? or going with just CatalogController and have inside all the catalogs methods?

Comment: created a catalogcontroller class and inside you put the methods referring to the catalog: 
/ api / catalog / language,
/ api / catalog / country,
/ api / catalog / employeeeetype,
etc ..